# Firebase Unity project fails to find BoringSSL-GRPC library during Xcode build

Tags: xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

I'm attempting to compile a Xcode `.xcworkspace` built by Unity that contains Google Firebase.  I tried all the solutions I could find online without any luck.  If you have any ideas I can try, can you please share?

The error I'm getting is that it can't find the `BoringSSL-GRPC` library.  I tried running `pod update` and `pod install` to resolve this and I can see while it does successfully install `BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.7)`, Xcode still gives this error even if I open the `.xcworkspace` file.

```
ld: library not found for -lBoringSSL-GRPC
```

When I add `use_frameworks!` to the podfile per a suggestion online, I get this error:

```
ld: framework not found FBLPromises
```

When I removed the above and then add `use_modular_headers!` per another suggestion, I get this error:

```
fatal error: module map file '/Users/xxx/Documents/Builds/DemoProj/Pods/Headers/Private/grpc/gRPC-Core.modulemap' not found
```

Each time, I changed the podfile, I'd run `pod update` and `pod install` before doing a clean build in Xcode.

Here are the versions I'm using:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.6
- Unity 2019.4.4f1
- Firebase 6.15.2
- Xcode 11.6 (11E708)
- CocoaPods 1.9.3

And here is my podfile:

```
use_frameworks!
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.24.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '6.24.0'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '6.24.0'
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '4.1.0'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', '1.15.0'
end
```

Notes:

- I've also tried adding `,:modular_headers => true` at the end of each pod which didn't work.
- I have a paid developer account and Xcode is configured for that account

Comment: `pod deintegrate` might help

Comment: No luck.  Doing clean build after `pod deintegrate` gives me the error `Undefined symbol: firebase::firestore...`.  If I then do `pod install` again, I get the same errors as above.

Comment: Try making sure there are no references to BoringSSL-GRPC in the project after `pod deintegrate` before `pod install` again

Comment: I ran `grep -R "BoringSSL-GRPC" *` and got only references to `Podfile.lock`.  Should I delete this file??

Comment: That shouldn't matter

Comment: That was the only file with references so no luck.